# Writing successful invitation to tender

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hardware, performance

I use macbook air for work and privately for many years. Every time I use to buy these laptops privately. However, I got recently funds to buy computers for my research group at university. Quite naturally, I wanted to continue using the same OS. But our financial department tells me it will be very difficult to achieve because they need to open a public invitation to tender and, most probably, there will be cheaper notebook offers on the market. This can be dealt with by formulating the requirements for the product, such that only the desired model comes into question.

I am interested in purchasing M1 chip MacBook Air for my students (M2 is a bit too expensive for my budget). What functionality can I indicate so that only this desired model comes into question and other products can be filtered?

Intended use: running computer algebra software such as Mathematica, debugging python and fortran codes before running them on dedicated clusters, preparing presentations, typing scientific texts, preparing illustrations with adobe illustrator.

Answer (score 3):

## Unique

> I am interested in purchasing M1 chip MacBook Air for my …
> This can be dealt with by formulating the requirements for the product, such that only the desired model comes into question.

So what makes the [M1 based MacBook Air](https://www.apple.com/macbook-air-m1/) unique?

- Require an ARM based processor;
- Require a portable/laptop device;
- Require a specific amount of memory suitable to the required tasks;

To ensure macOS:

- Require support of Apple's Neural Engine;
- Require Thunderbolt connectivity;
- Require support for a managed deployment; such as an MDM.

Are there other ARM based laptops that rival the MacBook Air or that fulfil these requirements?

> … running computer algebra software such as Mathematica, debugging python and fortran codes before running them on dedicated clusters, preparing presentations, typing scientific texts, preparing illustrations with adobe illustrator.

At the moment, the description of required tasks suggests Linux and [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) would be suitable.

## Apple Education

For writing the tender and justifications, **contact [Apple Education](https://www.apple.com/education/higher-education/how-to-buy/) and ask for their help**. Unlike the community here, Apple stand to gain from a successful tender and should be motivated to help you further.